# How does the GROUP BY clause manage the NULL values?

Tags: sql, sql-server

How does the GROUP BY clause manage the NULL values? Does it correspond to 
the general treatment of these values?

Comment: No, it does not correspond to the general treatment.  The general treatment is that two `NULL` values are not equal to each other.  In a `group by`, though, they are placed in the same group.  You can't always count on SQL for consistency.

Answer (score 36):

Null values of a column are grouped as a separate group.

See [**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cf122/2) demonstrating Group By and aggregate functions on nullable column

Comment: Do you mean "All NULL values belong to one group"?

Comment: @Sikder_Social yes .. all null values are treated as one group

Answer (score 35):

You mean, when you `GROUP BY` a nullable column? All rows with a NULL in the column are treated as if NULL was another value.

> If a grouping column contains null values, all null values are considered equal, and they are put into a single group.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx

Answer (score 5):

According to the sql:2003 specification (the late draft can be found [here](http://www.wiscorp.com/sql_2003_standard.zip) for free) - *4.4.2 The null value*:

> ...
> — Although the null value is neither equal to any other value nor not equal to any other value — it is unknown whether or not it is equal to any given value — in some contexts, multiple null values are treated together; for example, the <group by clause> treats all null values together

But above it is just a common informal notice about GROUP BY.
As far as we dive deeper: to remain the GROUP BY technically consistent with the idea that it's unknown whether two NULLs are equal or not to each other, they just use the definition of groups which is based not on the equality but on the "distinct values" (*7.9 <group by clause>, General rules*):

> b) Otherwise, the result of the  is a partitioning of
> the rows of T into the minimum number of groups such that, for each
> grouping column of each group, **no two values** of that grouping column
> **are distinct**...

And distinct values are defined in the following way:

> 3.1.6.8 **distinct** (of a pair of comparable values): Capable of being distinguished within a given context. Informally, not equal, **not both
> null**. A null value and a non-null value are distinct.

So, formally answering your question - NULLs are not treated as equal values but treated as not distinct values. In some cases, the equality treatment is used (obviously, you call that "general treatment"), but in other cases, the distinct treatment is used. That way, the spec remains logically consistent.

You can find more information about the NULL cases [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_(SQL)#When_two_nulls_are_equal:_grouping,_sorting,_and_some_set_operations).

Comment: Thank you for actually citing the standard

Answer (score 1):

Group By groups all the records with NULL values.