# MySQL - aggregating and GROUP BY with subqueries

Tags: mysql, group-by, case, aggregates

Is it possible to use GROUP BY to aggregate cells with subqueries? The database I'm working with contains customer order information (Order ID, Name, Address, Product, Option, etc). When a customer selects multiple options for a product they appear on separate rows. I need to aggregate all the product options onto the same row by mapping them to a new column, but not sure where to add the GROUP BY since I have subqueries...

Here's the query:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/83a399/4/0

Expected output:

```
Order ID | Qty | Option | Size | Product | Ref
-----------------------------------------------
12345    | 1   | R      | L    | Tee     | R / Tee L
12346    | 2   | Bl     | S    | Hood    | 2x Bl / Hood S
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: @forpas just added that, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must `group by Order ID` and aggregate:

```
SELECT 
  `Order ID`, 
  MAX(`Qty`) AS `Qty`, 
  MAX(`Option`) AS `Option`, 
  MAX(`Size`) AS `Size`,
  MAX(`Product`) AS `Product`,
  CONCAT_WS(' ',  
    MAX(CONCAT(
      CASE WHEN `Qty` > 1 THEN CONCAT(`Qty`, 'x ') ELSE '' END,
      `Option`, ' / ', `Product`,
      CASE WHEN COALESCE(`Size`, '') != '' THEN CONCAT('  ', `Size`) ELSE '' END
    )),
    MAX(`Size`)
  ) AS `Ref`
FROM (
  SELECT  
    o.`order_id` AS `Order ID`,
    op.`quantity` AS `Qty`,
    CASE 
      WHEN oo.`value` LIKE '%Red%' THEN  'R'
      WHEN oo.`value` LIKE '%Blue%' THEN  'Bl'
    END AS `Option`,
    CASE
      WHEN op.`name` LIKE '%t-shirt%' THEN 'Tee'  
      WHEN op.`name` LIKE '%hoodie%' THEN 'Hood'
      ELSE op.`name`
    END AS `Product`,
    CASE
      WHEN oo.`value` LIKE '%Small%' THEN 'S'
      WHEN oo.`value` LIKE '%Medium%' THEN  'M'
      WHEN oo.`value` LIKE '%Large%' THEN  'L'
      ELSE ''
    END AS `Size`
  FROM `order` AS o
  INNER JOIN `order_option` AS oo ON o.`order_id` = oo.`order_id`
  INNER JOIN `order_product` AS op ON op.`order_product_id` = oo.`order_product_id`
) AS `Orders`
GROUP BY `Order ID`
ORDER BY `Order ID` DESC
```

I made changes to your code like using proper joins and aliases for the tables.
See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/a1nLibcKEfETsggUhcwbwQ/0).
Results:

```
| Order ID | Qty | Option | Size | Product | Ref            |
| -------- | --- | ------ | ---- | ------- | -------------- |
| 12346    | 2   | Bl     | S    | Hood    | 2x Bl / Hood S |
| 12345    | 1   | R      | L    | Tee     | R / Tee L      |
```

Comment: Would it be possible to use a `JOIN` to a lookup table instead of using `CASE` statements? For example I'd have a table that stores the abbreviations for all products. The `JOIN` would only return the abbreviation from the second column of the table.

Comment: I don't know your design so I can't tell. But if efficiency matters a join is far less efficient than a CASE expression.

Comment: OK. Even for replacing something like US States with their 2-character abbreviation? (e.g. Texas -> TX).

Comment: If you are referring to efficiency that I mentioned, it is not about the values but about the join that is less efficient. But if you need to do this kind of change then by all means you should do it. Post a question where you will present the design that you have with sample data and expected results.

Comment: with the above query, is there still a way to aggregate the product options if the customer ordered two different types of products? See here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9e6954/1/0

Comment: If you mean 2 different products (because I son't see type of product existing in the tables), the way this query is structured is to return 1 product for each order and this is why MAX() is used. If there is a case of multiple products then it can be done with GROUP_CONCAT() which would return them as a comma separated list. But in this case what would be the other columns, like Qty?

Comment: Yes, so if a customer had two different products (1 t-shirt and 2 hoodies), then it would go on two separate rows because the number of items. Aggregation would still occur on the product options, so color and size would remain on the same row as the product.

Comment: I guess this means that you need `GROUP BY Order ID, Product` and instead of `MAX(Product)` just `Product`. I'm not sure but you can try it with your data.

Comment: I just realized this doesn't resolve the issue if the same Order ID has one product without a value for `Option`. In this example, ProductYZ won't show. Is this because of the `INNER JOIN` statements? https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/eDxcjp7VNgdR1t3vhkdRoe/0

Comment: `order_product` is joined on `op.order_product_id = oo.order_product_id`. So if a `order_product_id` exists in `order_product` but not in `order_option` it will not be returned.

Comment: Is there a way for the INNER JOIN to work on both situations?

Comment: Check this: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/eDxcjp7VNgdR1t3vhkdRoe/1 although I'm not sure if this fits your design.

Comment: Do you know why it’s not aggregating for ProductYZ so it’s all on one row? https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/eDxcjp7VNgdR1t3vhkdRoe/5

Comment: You `GROUP BY Order ID, Qty, Option, Product, Style`, so every distinct combination of these 5 columns is a different group.

Comment: I can't tell. You know the design of the tables and what the requirement is. I don't know why you designed the tables as they are.

Comment: The fiddle I made simply represents the way the ecommerce platform database stores order information. I don't have control over that. I only have control over how I query the existing tables.

Comment: Looks like the issue is related to how `NULL` values are treated in a `GROUP BY`. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22802078/how-does-the-group-by-clause-manage-the-null-values

Answer (score 1):

GROUP BY the column that have unique Keys and zse for the rest [aggregation functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html) Like MAX in your case

```
SELECT 
    `Order ID`, 
    `Qty`, 
    MAX(`Option`), 
    MAX(`Size`),
    `Product`,
        MAX(CONCAT (
            CASE 
                WHEN `Qty` > 1
                THEN CONCAT (`Qty`, 'x ')
                ELSE ''
                END,
            `Option`,
            ' / ',
            `Product`,
            CASE
                WHEN COALESCE (`Size`, '') != ''
                THEN CONCAT ('  ', `Size`)
                ELSE ''
                END
                ))
                AS `Ref`
    FROM (

        SELECT
            `order`.`order_id` AS `Order ID`,
            `order_product`.`quantity` AS `Qty`,

            CASE
                WHEN `order_option`.`value` LIKE '%Red%' THEN  'R'
                WHEN `order_option`.`value` LIKE '%Blue%' THEN  'Bl'
            END AS `Option`,

            CASE
                WHEN `order_product`.`name` LIKE '%t-shirt%' THEN 'Tee'
                WHEN `order_product`.`name` LIKE '%hoodie%' THEN 'Hood'
                ELSE `order_product`.`name`
            END AS `Product`,

            CASE        
                WHEN `order_option`.`value` LIKE '%Small%' THEN 'S'
                WHEN `order_option`.`value` LIKE '%Medium%' THEN  'M'
                WHEN `order_option`.`value` LIKE '%Large%' THEN  'L'

                ELSE ''
            END AS `Size`

    FROM
        `order`,
        `order_product`,
        `order_option`

    WHERE
        `order`.`order_id` = `order_option`.`order_id` AND 
        `order_product`.`order_product_id` = `order_option`.`order_product_id`

    ORDER BY `order`.`order_id` ASC

                ) AS `Orders`
 GROUP BY     
     `Order ID`, 
    `Qty`,
    `Product` ;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/83a399/6

Comment: I just tried that and I'm getting this error: #1055 - Expression #21 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'Orders.Option' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Comment: there is no orders.option in your query, soyou have changed the query,

Comment: even https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=9c8a6c3cf077c31684340982cd47c4d9 doesn't show an error it has full group by enabled

Comment: Figured out the issue. I needed to disable ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY from the sql mode.